# css - pseudo selector that targets text string between html tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to target `<a>` elements with class "topictitle" that have the text "glove" inside the `<a>` tags. Is this possible?

edit: I am using a wordpress WP scraper plugin, and the selector determines what it scrapes. I am going for a very specific scrape

Comment: What are you trying to do to this text?

Comment: Do you know how to do it with JavaScript? I suppose there isn't a way in css.

Comment: Is this for a specific event? You could use jQuery's replaceWith() function based on a specific event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
a[class*="topictitle"]
```

As far as formatting a specific text using the same  class, I don't think CSS attribute selection can go that further.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there isn't a way in CSS but there definitely is in JS.

Check the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh38/92wAr/)** or

### Try executing the Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .topictitle
            {
                font-size:30px;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            onload=function(){
                var link_array=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                for(i=0; i<link_array.length; i++)
                {
                    if(link_array[i].className.indexOf('topictitle')!=-1 && link_array[i].innerHTML=="glove")
                    {
                        link_array[i].style.backgroundColor="yellow";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class=topictitle>glove</a>
        <a>abc</a>
        <a class=topictitle>def</a>
        <a class=topictitle>glove</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have read the document on [CSS Selectors by W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), then you would be knowing that CSS selectors can only be used to target elements in the document tree.

At most you can select elements on the basis of `type`, `attributes`, `class`, `id`, `pseudo-class`, `pseudo-element`, `descendant`, `child` and `sibling`.

Moreover, this a situation where you can JavaScript instead of CSS as JavaScript will allow you to check on the basis of the text present inside an element.